# how to make a cell in a gridview as dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, grid

How to make a single cell in a grid to a dropdown. I have a editable grid in which all the rows are editable except two rows alone should be selectable from a dropdown. How can we achieve it? I could not start even how to proceed. Any ideas?

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="300" ID="gvService"
                            runat="server" GridLines="None" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Brown" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Cyan"
                            HeaderStyle-BackColor="ActiveCaption" ShowFooter="true">
                           <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Classic</HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblClassic" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Classic") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        ABC</HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblA" Visible='<%# ! IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ABC") %>' />
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ABC")%>'
                                            MaxLength="3" Columns="3">
                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can you post some markup of the gridview you are talking about and point out what exactly you want and don't want editable?

Comment: And in some rows you want the textbox to be a dropdown? How do you which rows they are?

Comment: I have asp:textbox through which i will make it available to all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're asking for, but you can just add another field with a dropdown in it like:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Classic</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblClassic" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Classic") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        ABC</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblA" Visible='<%# ! IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ABC") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ABC")%>'
            MaxLength="3" Columns="3">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Header="header">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="ddllbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And if you want to bind data to it explicitly you can do:

```
// In your aspx page
<asp:DropDownList ID="yourDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="yourTextFieldName" DataValueField="yourValueFieldName" OnDataBinding="yourddl_DataBinding">
</asp:DropDownList>

// In your codebehind .cs file
protected void yourddl_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
    // This could be a List of objects, DataTable, DataSet, whatever
    ddl.DataSource = GetCachedData();  
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: in the above code it will make the third column "header" as drop down right? but i want only first two row in that column to be dropdown.

Comment: The way to have different items in certain rows is to create both controls within a TemplateField. Then you can apply a conditional statement within the Visible property of each control. Then, only one control will display at a time, depending on the conditional result.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer is... on the gridview edit your templates.. it should have a drop down.. in that drop down you will find "edit item template" you would stick whatever control you want there.. and in the view it should be just text or a textbox whatever you with.

little mor einfo on template fields.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx